# Evaluate $\frac{d}{du} \int_{\ln u}^{\mathrm{e}^{u}} \cos(t^2) \, dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

As far as I'm concerned it should be made in this way: 
 
$F' = \cos (t^{2})$ so $ F = \sin (t^{2}) $

According to Fundamental theorem of calculus: 
 $ \frac{d}{du} \int_{\ln u}^{\mathrm{e}^{u}} \cos(t^2) \, dt = (F(\mathrm{e}^{u}) - F(\ln u))' = (\sin(\mathrm{e}^{2u}) -\sin((\ln u)^2)' = \cos(\mathrm{e}^{2u}) - \cos((\ln u)^2)  $

But it doesn't appear correct for me. I would appreciate point out where I've made (maybe fundamental) mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, $F\neq \sin(t^2)$.  We can't compute the anti-derivative in terms of elementary functions (the anti-derivative is actually a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)), but we don't need to find $F$ in order to compute $\displaystyle\frac{d}{du}\int_{\ln u}^{e^u}\cos(t^2)\,dt$.  We just need to recall (via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) that 
$$\begin{aligned} \frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t)\,dt &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[F(h(x)) - F(g(x))\right]\\ &= (F(h(x))^{\prime} - (F(g(x))^{\prime}\\ &=  F^{\prime}(h(x))\cdot h^{\prime}(x) - F^{\prime}(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x)\\ &= f(h(x))\cdot h^{\prime}(x) - f(g(x))\cdot g^{\prime}(x).\end{aligned}$$